# I am trying to upload images and resize them, so far the upload is working but my images are not resized

Tags: php, codeigniter

1. //my controller:

   ```
   public function infra_product() { 
     if($this->session->userdata('user_name') == TRUE)  {
     $data['user_name']=$this->session->userdata('user_name');      

     if(isset($_POST['sub1']))
     {
       $this->load->model('student_reg');
       $data['cat_id']=$_POST['cat_id'];

       if ($data['cat_id']=="1")
       {
         $loc='C:/xampp/htdocs/mahata/uploads/';     $files = $_FILES;       $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

         for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)    {
           $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

           $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$i];
           $ext = end((explode(".", $files['userfile']['name'][$i])));    echo $file;
      $id=$this->student_reg->infra_cat1($data);       $file= $id.".".$ext;        $filepath= $loc . $file;
        echo $filepath; 
           $this->load->library('image_lib');
         $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
         $config['source_image'] = $file;
         $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
         $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
         $config['width']         = 75;
         $config['height']       = 50;

      $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
      $this->image_lib->resize();  
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $filepath))
      {
          echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
      }
      else {
              echo "Upload failed";
           }       
       } 

       } 


           }
           $this->load->view('infra_product',$data);
       }
       else
       {
           redirect("index");
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `image_lib` library from Codeigniter. Please find below mentioned example.

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST'): 
    $this->load->library('image_lib'); 
    $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]); 
    $extension = $path_parts['extension'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "./uploads/img" . "." . $extension);
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE; 
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE; 
    $config['width'] = 200; 
    $config['height'] = 200; 
    $config['quality'] = 100; 
    $config['source_image'] = "./uploads/img" . "." . $extension;
    $this->image_lib->clear(); 
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();
   endif;
```